# Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-espresso

I'm trying to run gradle `Task :app:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest` on an Android 6.0 (API 23) device (both emulator and physical), and came across the error:

```
> Task :app:processDevDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/<name>/Projects/mobile-app-android/app/google-services.json
Starting 0 tests on Nexus_4_API_23(AVD) - 6.0
Tests on Nexus_4_API_23(AVD) - 6.0 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Nexus_4_API_23(AVD) - 6.0] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).

> Task :app:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/<name>/Projects/mobile-app-android/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/DEV/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've tried to isolate different causes of the problem. This error only pops up for Android 6.0, only when run `./gradlew connectedDevDebugAndroidTest` (instrumentation tests) in a terminal. I've upgraded some test libraries recently, in `app/build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.7.1'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
testImplementation ('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.16.0'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'  // Needed for EspressoTestRule

androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.16.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.github.fabioCollini:DaggerMock:0.8.4'
androidTestImplementation 'com.github.andrzejchm.RESTMock:android:0.1.3'
androidTestImplementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.1') {
    exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
    exclude module: 'okhttp'  // See: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/679
}

androidTestImplementation 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.4.0'
```

I suspected something in the latest version of `mockito` or `espresso` broke things, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten a "no tests found" error occasionally for specific devices, and cleaning the project, closing Android Studio, and restarting it seems to fix it.